# Trying to use getArgumentAtIndexAsObject from NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.h

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cocoapods, ocmock

maybe it's a silly thing... I'm trying to use

```
- (id)getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:(NSInteger)argIndex;
```

From NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.h, but I can't import the Category and if try to use the method is not available.

I'm using cocoaPods to get OCMock and I imported the header class:

```
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
```

maybe is a setting in cocoaPods?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a private method intended to be used by OCMock internally. It is not exported as part of the pod.

The reason is that I'm trying to keep the public API of OCMock, which must be supported for a long time, as small as possible.

If you want to use `getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:` in your project do so by adding the corresponding header file to your project. However, there is no guarantee that the method will be available in future versions of OCMock.

Comment: Erick, thanks for your reply. I think, it make sense. I was asking for that category because I've seen some examples using that method. Finally I sort it up with: 

   [[[controllerMocked stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        
        void (^sucessBlock)(EDUserMantle *user);
        [invocation getArgument:&sucessBlock atIndex:2];

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally as Erick said is not possible to use that method, so I used this way:

```
//We mock the methods loginWithUser
[[[controllerMocked stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {

    void (^sucessBlock)(NSString *token);

    [invocation getArgument:&sucessBlock atIndex:4];

    sucessBlock(@"1234567890");


}] loginWithUser:[OCMArg any] andPassword:[OCMArg any] withSuccess:[OCMArg any] withFailure:[OCMArg any]];
```

However the right answer is the Erick one :)